# Forced to manually select boot partition from UEFI menu every time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have got myself a new machine which has the following specs...

**MOBO**
GIGABYTE B360 AORUS Gaming 3 WiFi

and the BIOS (UEFI) menu looks as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PYroA_whjU)

I **first** installed **windows 10**, and **after that** I installed **Ubuntu 18.04**. And then I changed the boot partition order to point to ubuntu's partition. But to my surprise, the grub selection menu doesn't appear, instead, it directly boots into linux. I can manually selection boot partition from UEFI options, which is fine, but I want to know why isn't it working as expected. I have also tried out most of the solutions that appear with a simple google search. Also, my guess is that grub is not recognizing the windows kernel and hence not listing it (so by default it won't show the list and directly boot into linux)